# Chaining Reactive Asynchronus calls in spring

Tags: spring-webflux, webclient, project-reactor

I’m very new to the SpringReactor project.
Until now I've only used `Mono` from `WebClient` `.bodyToMono()` steps, and mostly `block()` those `Mono`'s or `.zip()` multiple of them.

But this time I have a usecase where I need to asynchronously call methods in multiple service classes, and those multiple service classes are calling multiple backend api.

I understand `Project Reactor` doesn't provide asynchronous flow by default.
But we can make the `publishing` and/or `subscribing` on different thread and make code asynchronous
And that's what I am trying to do.
I tried to read the documentation here [reactor reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) but still not clear.

For the purpose of this question, I’m making up this imaginary scenario. that is a little closer to my use case.

Let's assume we need to get a search response from google for some texts searched under images.

## ***Example Scenario***

Let's have an endpoint in a Controller
This endpoint accepts the following object from request body

```
MultimediaSearchRequest{
   Set<String> searchTexts; //many texts. 
   boolean isAddContent;
   boolean isAddMetadata;
}
```

in the controller, I’ll break the above single request object into multiple objects of the below type.
MultimediaSingleSearchRequest{

```
       String searchText;
       boolean isAddContent;
       boolean isAddMetadata;
}
```

This Controller talks to 3 Service classes.
Each of the service classes has a method `searchSingleItem`.
Each service class uses a few different backend Apis, but finally combines the results of those APIs responses into the same type of response class, let's call it  `MultimediaSearchResult`.

```
class JpegSearchHandleService {  
  public MultimediaSearchResult searchSingleItem
              (MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req){

    return comboneAllImageData( 
          getNameApi(req),
          getImageUrlApi(req),
          getContentApi(req)  //dont call if req.isAddContent false 
        )
  }
} 
 
class GifSearchHandleService { 
  public  MultimediaSearchResult searchSingleItem
               (MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req){

    return comboneAllImageData( 
          getNameApi(req),
          gitPartApi(req),
          someRandomApi(req),
          soemOtherRandomApi(req) 
        )
  }
}

class VideoSearchHandleService {  
  public MultimediaSearchResult searchSingleItem
              (MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req){

    return comboneAllImageData( 
          getNameApi(req),
          codecApi(req),
          commentsApi(req),
          anotherApi(req) 
        )
  }
```

}

In the end, my controller returns the response as a List of MultimediaSearchResult

```
Class MultimediaSearchResponse{

 List< MultimediaSearchResult> results;

}
```

If I want to use this all asynchronously using the project reactor. how to achieve it.

Like calling `searchSingleItem` method in each service for each searchText asynchronously.
Even within the services call each backend API asynchronously (I’m already using WebClient and converting response bodyToMono for backend API calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will outline a solution for the upper "layer" of your scenario.

The code (a simple simulation of the scenario):

```java
public class ChainingAsyncCallsInSpring {

    public Mono<MultimediaSearchResponse> controllerEndpoint(MultimediaSearchRequest req) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(req.getSearchTexts())
            .map(searchText -> new MultimediaSingleSearchRequest(searchText, req.isAddContent(), req.isAddMetadata()))
            .flatMap(multimediaSingleSearchRequest -> Flux.merge(
                classOneSearchSingleItem(multimediaSingleSearchRequest),
                classTwoSearchSingleItem(multimediaSingleSearchRequest),
                classThreeSearchSingleItem(multimediaSingleSearchRequest)
            ))
            .collectList()
            .map(MultimediaSearchResponse::new);
    }

    private Mono<MultimediaSearchResult> classOneSearchSingleItem(MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req) {
        return Mono.just(new MultimediaSearchResult("1"));
    }

    private Mono<MultimediaSearchResult> classTwoSearchSingleItem(MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req) {
        return Mono.just(new MultimediaSearchResult("2"));
    }

    private Mono<MultimediaSearchResult> classThreeSearchSingleItem(MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req) {
        return Mono.just(new MultimediaSearchResult("3"));
    }
}
```

Now, some rationale.

In the `controllerEndpoint()` function, first we create a `Flux` that will emit every single searchText from the request. We map these to `MultimediaSingleSearchRequest` objects, so that the services can consume them with the additional metadata that was provided with the original request.

Then, `Flux::flatMap` the created `MultimediaSingleSearchRequest` objects into a merged `Flux`, which (as opposed to `Flux::concat`) ensures that all three publishers are subscribed to eagerly i.e. they don't wait for one another. It works best on this exact scenario, when several independent publishers need to be subscribed to at the same time and their order is not important.

After the flat map, at this point, we have a `Flux<MultimediaSearchResult>`.

We continue with `Flux::collectList`, thus collecting the emitted values from all publishers (we could also use `Flux::reduceWith` here).

As a result, we now have a `Mono<List<MultimediaSearchResult>>`, which can easily be mapped to a `Mono<MultimediaSearchResponse>`.

The `results` list of the `MultimediaSearchResponse` will have 3 items for each searchText in the original request.

Hope this was helpful!

---

### Edit

Extending the answer with a point of view from the service classes as well. Assuming that each inner (optionally skipped) call returns a different type of result, this would be one way of going about it:

```java
public class MultimediaSearchResult {
    private Details details;
    private ContentDetails content;
    private MetadataDetails metadata;
}
```

```java
public Mono<MultimediaSearchResult> classOneSearchSingleItem(MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req) {
    return Mono.zip(getSomeDetails(req), getContentDetails(req), getMetadataDetails(req))
        .map(tuple3 -> new MultimediaSearchResult(
                tuple3.getT1(),
                tuple3.getT2().orElse(null),
                tuple3.getT3().orElse(null)
            )
        );
}

// Always wanted
private Mono<Details> getSomeDetails(MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req) {
    return Mono.just(new Details("details")); // api call etc.
}

// Wanted if isAddContent is true
private Mono<Optional<ContentDetails>> getContentDetails(MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req) {
    return req.isAddContent()
        ? Mono.just(Optional.of(new ContentDetails("content-details"))) // api call etc.
        : Mono.just(Optional.empty());
}

// Wanted if isAddMetadata is true
private Mono<Optional<MetadataDetails>> getMetadataDetails(MultimediaSingleSearchRequest req) {
    return req.isAddMetadata()
        ? Mono.just(Optional.of(new MetadataDetails("metadata-details"))) // api call etc.
        : Mono.just(Optional.empty());
}
```

Optionals are used for the requests that might be skipped, since `Mono::zip` will fail if either of the zipped publishers emit an empty value.

If the results of each inner call extend the same base class or are the same wrapped return type, then the original answer applies as to how they can be combined (`Flux::merge` etc.)

Comment: the idea is to call the services repeatedly for each search text. as i said in question..but let me update the example model to make it clear

Comment: @ThrowableException I see. The basic idea is still the same, let me update my answer in light of this.

Comment: I think I did not ask my question correctly. For now, let me upvote your answer, and instead of changing the question, I’ll ask a separate question, with lesser details.

Comment: I was more interested in the syntax for writing reactive functional code for chaining multiple `getItemXXXDetails()` backend API calls, where some `XXX` are conditional based upon request. and this will happen for many Items

Comment: @ThrowableException I see! If you just update your question with this last bit, I can propose some solutions for this as well.

Comment: @ThrowableException extended the answer based on your comments, since it is mentioned in the original question too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248964/discussion-between-throwableexception-and-cpigeon).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I marked your answer as accepted.. but before I saw your updated answer I created this example dummy code on github to  better explain the question. Had TODOs for the problem scenarios
https://github.com/mps-learning/spring-reactive-example/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mps/springreactiveexample